# Alternative to standard Erdos-Renyi random graphs that have better clustering and degree distributions?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Is there a widely accepted alternative to Erdos-Renyi random graphs that addresses their issues with 1) degree distributions not having heavy enough tails and 2) clustering coefficients being too low?

My understanding is that Barabasi-Albert models for example don’t work as well as one would like for this purpose and that there have been a number of misleading results with them. What else is there? For example, do stochastic block models fix the clustering and degree distribution issues?

Comment: What is "heavy enough" tails, and what is "too low"? What is "this purpose"?

Comment: In a sense, you're looking for alternatives to Barabasi–Albert. The Erdős–Rényi model is not a model for statisticians: it is primarily a tool for probabilistic combinatorics, in which setting we don't care about heavy tails and low clustering coefficients.

Comment: @Henning “Heavy enough” meaning able to handle complex networks with skewed degree distributions. ”This purpose” is producing a generative model for a network that might have a skewed degree distribution

Comment: @Misha Thank you for that distinction, I didn’t know that. Is there a type of network you’d suggest for statisticians looking for a generative model for a complex network that could have a skewed degree distribution?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-free_network#The_Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model) for info on graphs with a "power-law degree distribution" (degree distributions not having heavy enough tails). Also [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3015) on the "preferential attachment model" (satisfies both the properties you are after).

Comment: Preferential attachment was already mentioned in the question, though of course you might disagree with the summary given.

Comment: @JRyan I’ve seen that Wikipedia page. Are all those models “generative”?

Comment: @JohnDoeVsJoeSchmoe the preferential attachment model is generative

Comment: I know that it generates the model in a procedural way, but would you describe the resulting model as generative? In the sense that it suggests a probability distribution that can be used to simulate data (edges)?

Comment: No, It is apparently a mechanistic model (see http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/courses/7000/csci7000-001_2011_L13.pdf)